# UIView always on top

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a very complex view hierarchy . Having a Master - Detail View Controller with UINavigation Controller in each section and each view controllers have their own UViews inside them. I have a overlay view which supports a buffer or a holder for Drag and Drop event . I want this view at the top of all my subviews irrespective of Hierarchy at any given point of time.

Is there a way so that I can place a UIView always on top.

Something like

```
   overlayView.alwaysOntop = YES;
```

I can manually use function like , bring subview to front , insert sub view above , below etc , but that makes my application very complex.

Comment: why don't you create an UIView for your `overlayView` and a second `UIView` for your other views? you should bring to the front the `overlayView` only once, and you can work freely on your other `UIView` (add or remove any subviews to or from it), they are always below your `overlayView`. it look more logical way than clown the bring to front or insert above/below methods in every individual case.

Comment: Ok. I tried that . I have a window where my window.vie.rootViewController is set as my splitViewcontroller so this transition has to be done by window. 

[window insertsubview:overlayview above:slitviewController.view];

but this didn't worked . I think this has some constraints on the parameters . Do you have any clue . How do I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding the view as a sub view of the navigation view

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubView:yourView];
```

As long as you don't add other subviews to your navigation controller view it should stay at the top of the hierarchy. You may have to move its position slightly too.